# Accessing to mysql from host to container in cli

Tags: mysql, docker

I created my container like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 33060:3306 myimage
```

Then I try connect from host to mysql server in container:

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -P 33060
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

It odd because in Navicat only I changed the port and work fine:
[image]

But If I have the IP of the container:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mycontainer
172.17.0.55
```

Then I can connect to mysql server successfully:

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -h 172.17.0.55
```

But it is a tedious task have to check the ip each time I create a new container to connect to mysql. There any settings I can do to make this task simpler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a Docker issue. By default the `mysql` command-line client will connect to a local (Unix) socket instead of a network one, even if you specify `-P`.

This behavior is described in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs **even if a --port or -P option** is given

You have to pass the `-hlocalhost` option, or you can set your connection defaults in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`